# Is the use of require related to package.json in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Suppose if my package.json file has 'random_module' as one of the values under the 'dependencies' key then will using the code var rm = require("random_module"); work? My question is whether the argument for require works for any of the modules listed under the dependencies key of the package.json file in the main directory.

Comment: Did you try this? I think it‘s a question you could solve by just trying out :) If there is an error, it can help you or you can ask again about that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does, provided you install your dependencies with `npm install` or `yarn install`, but it is not only limited to this.

A call to `require` loads modules from `node_modules` if you specify an argument starting with the name of a module. But, you can also `require` custom modules or exports from other js files relative to your project, e.g. you can `require("./MyModule")`, which will import exports from MyModule.js placed in current directory (the one you keep the js file that calls the `require` in).

Comment: How come you omitted the '.js' extension when using require("./MyModule") ?

Comment: @Ikim node's `require` is a bit smart and, if you don't specify the extension, it will first look for such a file with `.js` extension, then, if it doesn't find such one, for a `.json` file, and finally for a `.node` (native node addon) file

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works for all you declare in the `dependencies` object in `package.json`.. Beware that you should use `devDependencies` object and have `key,value` which are dependents for your project..

`dependencies` object is a production ready

`deDependencies` is for development..

I would prefer to place all my `packages` in devDependencies unless it is for production.

you can pull a dependency in two ways -

commonJS way:  `require('')`

ES6 way:  `import statements..`

Once you have a dependency given in `package.json`
give `npm install` or `yarn install`.

But I would prefer `yarn` over `npm` because `yarn` us faster than `npm`.. And now all the dependencies get downloaded into node_moudules folder.

example: if you say `require('react')` in your code, it actually reads the dependency from nodu_modules folder.

To understand the `import`, `require` more you need to know when to have a `named import` and when to have a `default export and then import`..

```
default => export default ...;
 named => export const someData = ...;
```

example#01:

## Person.js

```
const person = { name: "firstName" }'
export default person;
```

Now you should use import Person from 'Person'

example#02:

## clean.js

```
 export const clean = () => ...}
then you should use import { clean } from 'clean'
```

default export:

```
import person from './person';
import prs from './person';
```

named export:

```
import { smth } from './utility';
import { smth as Smth } from './utility';
import * as bundled from './utility';
```